# Disabling stacking on nav-pills in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a set of nav-pills which stack nicely when the page shrinks. However I'd rather they didn't stack for this usage. Does anyone have a quick way to disable the stacking for the nav-pills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pills by default are floated, there are basically only two options:

A) Give the surrounding element a fixed width (which is only possible, if you know how many pills there are and how wide they are, but its dangerous since the width may differ on different browsers/devices or depending on the users prferences.

B) Replace the floating with another styling of your choice, such as `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`.